# No module named Setup, import error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run through the Guestbook tutorial on the google appengine website. I have Python 2.7.13 and Python 3.6 installed. However when I'm trying to run the program locally via dev_appserver.py ./ command I'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\sameer\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\dev_appserver.py", line 11, in <module>
import bootstrapping.bootstrapping as bootstrapping   
File  "C:\Users\sameer\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin\bootstrapping\bootstrapping.py", line 9, in <module>
import setup 
ImportError: No module named 'setup'
```

I've tried installing and updating setuptools but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which Python is being used?  If you don't need 3.6, you can uninstall it.  If you need both, you should look into virtualenv.

Comment: Yes, I reinstalled python and it seems to have solved the problem.